# How to replace inline javascript in rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller

My existing sessions_controller use inline javascript exit to root_path as follow:

```
render inline: "<script>window.location.replace('#{url}')</script>"
```

It worked in Rails 4 but not in Rails 5.
Most document talking about calling javascript in view.
But this is controller.
From what I understand I should replace with

```
render :js => "myNewJavascriptFunction();"
```

Which I did tried create myNewJavascriptFunction() in another file eg: 
views/sessions/create.js.erb it has error

> undefined method `myNewJavascriptFunction' for

Help:

1. How or Should I put the javascript in views/sessions/create.js.erb
2. Can we put the javascript in assets to work with controller and how.

Here my existing codes:
In SessionsController

```
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    if params.permit[:remember_me]
      cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    else
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    end
        # render :js => refresh(root_path) #not work
        # redirect_to root_path            #not work with JQM
        render inline: "<script>window.location.replace('#{url}')</script>" #not work with Rails 5
    rescue 

    render inline: "<script>window.location.replace('#{url}')</script>" #not work with Rails 5
  end
```

views/sessions/create.js.erb

```
function refresh(url='/') {
  window.location.replace(\'#{url}\');
}
```

menu call

```
- if login?
  %li
    %a{"data-panel" => "main", :href => logout_path, "data-ajax"=>"false"} Sign Out
- else
  %li
    %a{:href=>new_session_path, "data-panel" => "main"} Sign In
  %li
    %a{:href=>new_identity_path, "data-panel" => "main"} Sign Up
%li
  = link_to "Refresh", "#", :onclick=>"window.location.replace('/')"
- if !login?    
  = link_to image_tag( 'facebook-sign-in-button.png'), '/auth/facebook', rel: "external"
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to have a views/sessions/create.js.erb

Just replace `render inline: "<script>window.location.replace('#{url}')</script>"` with `render js: "window.location.replace('#{url}')"`

Comment: Thank, Now I have another error   "Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding."

Comment: If I disable forgery protection by add "protect_from_forgery except: :create" in SessionsController this error disappeared but the new pages show only "window.location.replace('/')"

Comment: @T.Kul I think I need some more information then. How do you call create? Via normal form post or via ajax or something else?

Comment: It's a login/ logout processes using omniauth call back (login). It's call from (see updated Question)